# Oracle - How to add new columns and set default values while under load

Tags: oracle, performance

I have an oracle database and one of the tables contains monetary fields:

```
desc example_table;
Name      Null     Type
--------- -------- ------
...
PRICE     NOT NULL NUMBER
SHIPPING           NUMBER
DISCOUNT           NUMBER
...
```

I need to modify this table to also contain corresponding currency codes for each of the fields. And these new columns need to be populated with default values corresponding to the columns that already exist.

Here is my thought on how to do this:

```
alter table example_table add (
    price_currency_code    varchar2(3)
  , shipping_currency_code varchar2(3)
  , discount_currency_code varchar2(3)
);

update example_table
   set price_currency_code = 'USD'
     , shipping_currency_code = case when shipping is null 
                                     then null 
                                     else 'USD' 
                                end
     , discount_currency_code = case when discount is null 
                                     then null 
                                     else 'USD' 
                                end
;
```

Lastly, I need to make sure that the nullable property of each new column matches that of the original columns:

```
alter table example_table modify (
    price_currency_code varchar2(3) not null
);
```

Is this the correct (and best performance) solution to solve this problem? Is there another way to accomplish the same results that might perform better on a table that contains hundreds of millions of rows?

If this approach is used to update a production table for a website, how might this update affect the user experience on the website while the update is running?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  In more recent versions, adding additional `NOT NULL` columns with a `DEFAULT` doesn't require touching the data stored at a row level so it is a very quick operation.  In earlier versions, the approach you outline here would make more sense.

Comment: Oracle version: 11.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the trick that Justin mentioned, e.g.:

```
alter table example_table add (
    price_currency_code    varchar2(3) default 'USD' not null
  , shipping_currency_code varchar2(3)
  , discount_currency_code varchar2(3)
);

alter table example_table modify price_currency_code default null;
```

This allows you to set all the existing rows to `'USD'` but not have the default remain for subsequent inserts. Of course, if `'USD'` is a sensible default then you could skip the second `alter`.

Then, it's just a matter of the other columns. Depending on the number of rows that meet the conditions, you may choose to have one update statement or two, e.g.:

```
update example_table set shipping_currency_code = 'USD' where shipping is not null;
update example_table set discount_currency_code = 'USD' where discount is not null;
```

If there are a large number of records involved you may need a different strategy.

Another option to consider is to use [DBMS_REDEFINITION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS042).